# T-SQL How to change hierarchy levels to ascend instead of descend?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have very simple query that show all parents of all childs:

```
;with cte as (
    select 1 as Level, Child, Parent from TABLE
    union all
    select t.Level + 1, t.Child, t.Parentfrom TABLE t
    inner join cte on t.Child = cte.Parent
)
select distinct * from t
```

output:

```
Level|Child|Parent|
 3   |  A  |      |
 2   |  B  |   A  |
 1   |  C  |   B  |
 1   |  D  |   B  |
```

How do I achieve the levels to be in ascending order, so that the top parent begins with 1, for example:

```
Level|Child|Parent|
 1   |  A  |      |
 2   |  B  |   A  |
 3   |  C  |   B  |
 3   |  D  |   B  |
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DENSE_RANK` in your final query. Something like:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Level] DECS) AS [Level]
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with parents and work your way down:

```
with cte as (
      select 1 as Level, Child, Parent
      from TABLE
      where parent is null
      union all
      select cte.Level + 1, t.Child, t.Parent
      from TABLE t join
           cte
           on cte.Child = t.Parent
     )
select * 
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3b2b9ff1a3cb22a7690c5d5b633f7f34) is a db<>fiddle.